# When setting up Windows EventLog Forwarding (WEF), does the forwarding machine keep a local copy of the log?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, logging, windows-event-log

I am curious if the server forwarding said logs keeps a local copy in addition to forwarding, or if all logs it generates are immediately forwarded to the collector? I cannot find detailed information about this in any setup procedure. It appears that the forwarding machine keeps a copy by default. I am trying to setup a centralized logging server in order to keep local disk space free of large log files.

Referenced:

- [Use Windows Event Forwarding to help with intrusion detection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/use-windows-event-forwarding-to-assist-in-intrusion-detection)
- [Best practice for configuring EventLog forwarding in Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4494356/best-practice-eventlog-forwarding-performance)
- [Monitoring what matters - Windows Event Forwarding for everyone](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jepayne/monitoring-what-matters-windows-event-forwarding-for-everyone-even-if-you-already-have-a-siem)
- [How To Set Up Windows Event Log Forwarding In Windows Server 2016](https://adamtheautomator.com/windows-event-log-forwarding/)

Answer (score 1):

Event forwarding doesn't do anything with the local log content. The local logs remain and are aged out pursuant to the event log overwrite policy.